# Format TSQL onto one line

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Our company uses an old app which reads TSQL from a .INI file. Due to how the app process the INI file the TSQL has to be all on one line. I use Poor Mans TSQL Formatter to get everything nice and tidy for things like SPs, but am wondering if there's something out there to do the reverse - take nicely formatted TSQL and shove it all onto one line (removing carriage returns , line breaks etc).
I'm working in SSMS but also use Notepad++, and will happily use some other editor if it has the functionality.

Comment: It is valid to have line breaks inside string literals in TSQL and removing these globally will change the semantics of the query. Something you need to consider?

Comment: I don't believe this will occur with the types of query I will be formatting to one line, but thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using Notepad++

Select the statement that is over multiple lines then on the menu: TextFX>TextFX Edit>Unwrap Text

[image]

And for even greater ease you can assign it to a keyboard shortcut using the shortcut mapper (Settings>Shortcut Mapper)

[image]

Comment: I was curious about the downvote too. My only question is if the TSQL has something like a table field of Quantity on one line with no spaces after it, and a FROM at the start of the other line, will this know not to combine them (into QuantityFROM - if simply removing line breaks/carriage returns then I assume not), or is there an option to configure so this doesn't happen (auto-add a space or similar)?

Comment: KrustyGString - I've just tried that and it appears to work perfectly!

Comment: Update: I've installed and it looks like it does automatically add an additional space so no characters are combined by accident. Thanking you very much.

Answer (score 17):

Using **Notepad++ (Without any plugin)**

After lot's of googling I found that there are no plugins like **TextFX** and **PoorMansTSqlFormatter** are available in x64 bit version of notepad++ even not needed.

Notepad++  -->  Write Query --> Edit --> Blank Options --> Remove Unnecessary Blank and EOL.

[image]

That's it.

Comment: Fwiw, there's a 64-bit version of the formatter plugin available for manual download/install at http://architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx, and this will be included in the new Plugin Manager whenever the Notepad++ maintainer establishes a process.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the minify comment to remove all the unnecessary space in the [Poor Mans TSQL Formatter](http://architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx#Tips_amp_Tricks_8)

```
[minify]

[/minify]
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Martin's answer and that is probably the way to go.  But I'll point out that you can just use string manipulation to turn carriage returns and line feeds into spaces.  This is particularly easy in the later versions of SSMS that enable limted use of regex in the find/replace dialog.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012:

1. Highlight the selected text and use 'Find and Replace' (ctrl + h)
2. Check: use Regular Expressions
3. Find: \n
4. Replace with: LEAVE BLANK